# Laplace equation of composite function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, laplacian

Suppose we have $f(x,y)$, which satisfies Laplaces equation: $\frac{\delta^2f}{\delta x^2}+\frac{\delta^2f}{\delta y^2}=0$

Does $f(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$ also satisfy Laplace equation?

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3873275/fx-y-is-harmonic-then-so-is-the-function-gx-y-f-fracxx2y2-frac/3873320#3873320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to change the Cartesian to the polar cordinates.
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Y^2}=0 \to
\begin{cases} 
X=R\cos(a)\\
Y=R\sin(a)\\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial R^2}+\frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial f}{\partial R}+ \frac{1}{R^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases} 
x=r\cos(a)\\
y=r\sin(a)\\
X=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{1}{r}\cos(a)\\
Y=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{1}{r}\sin(a)\\
\end{cases} \to r=\frac{1}{R}$$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial R}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{dr}{dR}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{1}{R^2}$

$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial R^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}\frac{1}{R^4}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{2}{R^3}$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial R^2}+\frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial f}{\partial R}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}=  
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}\frac{1}{R^4}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{1}{R^3} +\frac{1}{R^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}=0
$$
$$  
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{1}{r} +\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}=0
$$
Then, comming back to the cartesian coodinates :
$$\left(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}\right)f\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\:,\:\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \right)=0$$
So, the answer to the question is yes.