# $f(x,y)$ is harmonic then so is the function $g(x,y) = f(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

If $f(x,y)$ is harmonic then so is the function $g(x,y) = f(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$.

Since $f$ is harmonic we have $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = 0$.

Then I tried changing to polar coordinated. But  I am unable to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

This is very nice. I will give you a hint, and let you work on it, and then later return to complete the solution, if that is needed (this is exactly the reason why I didn't make this a comment).

Use the following fact : a function is harmonic if and only if it is the real part (or imaginary part) of some holomorphic function.

The proof of one direction is straightforward, by establishing the Laplace conditions. The other part requires some more ingredients. (See Proposition 28 from [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/09/22/246a-notes-1-complex-differentiation/).)

Now try to use this to establish what you want. It should be really easy once you know this.